# Видимость кнопки на форме C#

Tags: c#

Доброе время суток, возникла такая проблема. 
В программе кидаю кнопку на форму и при инициализации ставлю свойство Visible в значение false, в процессе выполнения программы я ее включаю, но на форме она так и не отображается. Но если я ее в начале не буду отключать видимость, а отключу в середине выполнения программы и снова включу, то все будет нормально. 
Код когда кнопка выкл и результат выполнения работы.

```
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBox2.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        FileStream a = new FileStream("xran.by", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        a.Close();
        FileStream b = new FileStream("record.by", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        b.Close();
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        exit.Visible = false;
    }
```

Код где я вкл видимость:

```
    private void record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //название нажатой кнопки record
    {
        fPaint = true;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        groupBox1.Visible = false;
        exit.Visible = true; // кнопка, которая должна появится, название exit
        Refresh();
        recordOut();
        fTime = true;
    }
```

Скриншоты: картинка №1 место где мне не нужна видимость кнопки, №2 где нужна видимость кнопки. 
Картинка 1 
[image: картинка 1]

Картинка 2 (вот тут нужна кнопка выхода)
[image: картинка 2]


Далее убираю строчку видимости кнопки exit, при инициализации в приложении. И вот такой результат (картинка 3 и 4).
Картинка 3 (но тут не нужно, чтобы она была видима)
[image: картинка 3]

Картинка 4 (тут все хорошо)
[image: картинка 4]

Позже я выхожу и она исчезает и далее нормально функционирует, проблема в том, чтобы она отображаться должна только в разделе рекордов. И я не могу понять почему только она так криво работает, когда остальное все функционирует нормально. 
Картинка 5 (выход из раздела рекорды и тут все хорошо)
[image: картинка 5]

Comment: Метод `record_Click` не вызывается между первой и второй картинками.

Comment: да, он вызывается только когда я захожу в таблицу рекордов

Comment: Как Вы попадаете из состояния окна на первой картинке, в состояние окна на второй картинке? Если в это время не выполняется код `exit.Visible = true;`, почему Вы считаете, что кнопка `exit` должна стать видимой?

Comment: Я после ввода логина и пароля захожу в меню, потом жму на таблицу рекордов или начинаю играть, позже как я проигрываю или нажимаю кнопку "Таблица рекордов" я перехожу к картинке 2
вот ссылка на промежуточное состояние.
http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1511/d2/949010771e02.png

Answer (score 1):

Инициализация формы это слишком рано, попробуйте:

```
Form.Load Event:
Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.
```

Comment: А почему тогда все остальное работает?

Comment: В Form.Init считается что объекты могут быть еще не до конца  сконструированы, а могут быть только аллоцироваными.

Comment: Но ведь в конструкторе вроде можно прописывать начальные значения свойств. Вот скриншот. http://s017.radikal.ru/i420/1511/2d/37df09f9f2bd.png

Comment: WinForms это просто такая C# обертка над WinAPI, поэтому не всегда все можно сделать в конструкторе, а нужно дожидаться пока полноценно заработает очередь сообщений.